# viewWillTransition called from different Tab with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I using a `UITabBarController` with 5 items, each of which has its own viewController.

Three of the viewControllers have their own `viewWillTransition` function for when the screen is rotated.

If I am on Tab4 which does not have a `viewWillTransition` function and rotate the screen, the `viewWillTransition` function of Tab3 is called and the app crashed with `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`.

I found how to fix this (by only running each on its own viewController:

```
guard self == self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController else { return }
// custom actions for each viewController:
createGraph()

func createGraph() {
    viewGraphs.subviews.forEach { v in
        v.removeFromSuperview() }
   // etc.
 }
```

But can someone explain why Tab3's viewWillTransition function is called when I am on Tab4?

Comment: Well, it does still exist after all. It would be better to show use the `viewWillTransition` code; you must be using force unwrapping somewhere, and _that_ is the problem to look out for.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it does still exist".  I guess my confusion is why one viewController's `viewWillTransition` is called when in another.  I added the line of code where it crashes in the original post.

Comment: Well you didn't show enough to give a sense of where the crash is? If `viewGraphs` is an implicitly unwrapped Optional, that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> But can someone explain why Tab3's viewWillTransition function is called when I am on Tab4?

Why not? In a tab view controller, all the tab view controllers exist simultaneously. An existing view controller is an existing view controller. It's part of the view controller hierarchy, so it gets `transition` calls.

It is easy to prove that this is normal with a vanilla project. Make a tab view controller and give it three children that are instances of the same view controller class, and implement `viewWillTransition`. Run the project and rotate the interface. *All three* instances will fire their `viewWillTransition`.

Nor is this unique to tab view controllers. The same is true of a navigation controller. Push several instances of the same view controller onto a navigation controller and rotate the interface. `viewWillTransition` fires for all of them.

However, your solution here is probably wrong. You should not have to guard against which view controller is the current tab. Instead you should stop using implicitly unwrapped Optionals or forced unwrapping of Optionals. Your "solution" seems like a bandage that merely hides the real wound.

Comment: `viewGraphs` is a UIView in storyboard with an outlet: `@IBOutlet weak var viewGraphs: UIView!`.  That's not an unwrapped optional, is it?  (I am still pretty new at this - it's NOT Fortran!) 
 
It only crashes before a graph has been created (and only on that line), i.e., when the subviews.count = 0.  I thought this would work similarly to iterating through an array (`for i in 0..< array.count { print(i) }` - if the array has no elements, nothing gets printed but it doesn't crash.

Comment: I did create a project, added a UITabBarController, which came with its two viewControllers and saw that both `viewWillTransition`s fired regardless of which tab I was on - that's what I was trying to understand.

I guess I thought that each viewController was a separate entity that would only run its code - like `viewWillAppear` - when on its own tab and was having a hard time understanding why they both fired.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Each thing is the thing it is, and not some other thing. These are events about what is happening. They fire when that thing is happening. `viewWillTransition` fires when the app rotates. `viewWillAppear` fires when that view controller's view is about to occupy the screen. They are simply different things that happen.

Comment: Yes, but each `viewWillAppear` only fires on its own viewController whereas apparently, all `viewWillTransition`s fire on any/all viewControllers.  I now understand that.

Comment: But what I am wondering now is why it crashes when `subviews.count = 0`.

Comment: "Yes, but each viewWillAppear only fires on its own viewController whereas apparently, all viewWillTransitions fire on any/all viewControllers" No, that's not it. `viewWillAppear` fires on every view controller that is in fact about to have its view appear. But there is only ever one of those at a time. `viewWillTransition` fires on every view controller that is in fact undergoing rotation. But there can be many of those at one time.

Comment: "But what I am wondering now is why it crashes" Yes, that's what it said in my answer. The real problem is your use of Optionals. But you have not revealed that to us. You have not shown enough code to answer the question of what the crash actually is.

Comment: It literally crashes on that first line of the `createGraph` function (shown) which was called by `viewWillTransition`.

Comment: So it crashes on `viewGraphs.subviews.forEach`? So that's why I'm asking what is nil here? Is it `viewGraphs`?

Comment: `viewGraphs` is a UIView in storyboard with an outlet: `@IBOutlet weak var viewGraphs: UIView!`

Comment: Yep, that's what I keep telling you. That's an implicitly unwrapped Optional. It is nil so you can crash. Any time you have an exclamation mark, like `UIView!`, that means, "please crash me". You can hardly be surprised when you do crash. Do a nil test before you refer to it, so that doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh!  I thought that because it had been created in Storyboard and given an outlet that it could never be nil.  Is there a way to ensure that views and labels and buttons etc. created in Storyboard are never nil?